# Am Chart does not load chart after ajax call

Tags: angularjs, ajax, amcharts

I fetch data from API by making ajax call then pass this data to the chart. 
I am not able to render the chart. Can anyone suggest me what may be the issue?

This is my ajax call

You can see after ajax call i am trying to push to scope variable and trying to add to chart.

for reference please find in this link http://jsfiddle.net/w3vpc35o/41/

```
  angular.module('amChartsDirectiveExample', ['amChartsDirective']).controller('amChartsController', function ($scope) {
$scope.call = function(){
  $http({
            method: "get",
            global: false,
            async: true,
            url: "server/test.php
        }).
        success(function(data) {
      /*Assume data like like [{
        year: 2005,
        income: 23.5,
        expenses: 18.1
    }, {
        year: 2006,
        income: 26.2,
        expenses: 22.8
    }, {
        year: 2007,
        income: 30.1,
        expenses: 23.9
    }, {
        year: 2008,
        income: 29.5,
        expenses: 25.1
    }, {
        year: 2009,
        income: 24.6,
        expenses: 25
    }]*/
   $scope.rest = data
  $scope.amChartOptions = {
    data:$scope.res ,
    type: "serial",
    theme: 'black',
    categoryField: "year",
    rotate: true,
    pathToImages: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.13.0/images/',
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    chartScrollbar: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        gridPosition: "start",
        parseDates: false
    },
    valueAxes: [{
        position: "top",
        title: "Million USD"
    }],
    graphs: [{
        type: "column",
        title: "Income",
        valueField: "income",
        fillAlphas: 1,
    }]
}
  });
 }


$scope.call();

  });
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: I have updated code. I have used async call too. But not use.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned if you use some angular wrapper for amCharts or not, but if not, maybe you called var chart = AmCharts.makeChart(...) before the ajax call completed and you forgot to call chart.validateData(); after?

Will greatly help if you will post here some full code related to this issue

EDIT

It's seems that you use [GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular](https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular).

Use the technique mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular): 'Promise based chart rendering' to resolve the data in async: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vpc35o/83/

In general, what you need to do is to create the ChartOptions like this:

```
this.amChartOptions = $timeout(function(){
        return {
            data: this.dataFromPromise(),
            type: "serial",
...
}.bind(this), 1000)
```

and fetch the data in async using something like this:

```
this.dataFromPromise = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "/server/endpoint"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: I have updated what i was trying to do and i also given link where you can find its directive and respective JS files